# cambiar el color de un dropdown-item de bootstrap 4

Tags: css, bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Buen dia, tengo un autocomplete en un input para unos productos en el cual se ve asi

[image: Autocomplete sin hacer hover, solo digitando]

Si pongo el mouse encima lo cual entiendo que es Hover, se ve así lo cual está bien

[image: Haciendo hover en una de las opciones]

he modificado el color del fondo del hover haciendo que sea un gris en este codigo de bootstrap 4

```
.dropdown-item:hover, .dropdown-item:focus
{
  color: #16181b;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #adb3ba;
}
```

Ahora....

si bajo por ejemplo a la tercera opcion con la flecha de abajo del teclado, viene siendo BUJE PVC PRESION ROSCADO 1.1/2"X1/2 PAVCO, este me lo pone en la caja como debe ser pero no cambia el color del fondo por lo cual es complicado saber que opcion recorro con el teclado, (es mas rapido que coger el mouse y señalar), aqui el screenshoot

[image: Bajo hacia la opcion 3 de las sugerencias]

Lo que quiero es que asi como el hover, tambien cambie el color de la opcion en la cual voy con el teclado, se supone que eso deberia ser 'Active' en este codigo

```
.dropdown-item.active, .dropdown-item:active {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #007bff; /* un tipo de azul le puse */
}
```

Pero no funciona, ya he probado en 3 navegadores, alguna idea?

Comment: Inspecciona el elemento seleccionado conforme vas bajando en las opciones y checa si hay alguna clase que se le esté añadiendo, de lo contrario, tendrás que adjuntarle un evento de `keyDown` y agregarle manualmente la clase que estés ocupando para cambiar el color.

Comment: probaste con la pseudo-clase `:focus`?

Comment: @IvanS95 Pseudocalse viene siendo asi? .dropdown-item.focus, .dropdown-item:focus {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #007bff; /* un tipo de azul le puse */
}

Comment: Seria solo el `dropdown-item:focus`, no hay una clase con ese nombre; si estas apuntando al elemento correcto deberia de verse reflejado

Comment: @IvanS95 puse tal cual asi y no funcionó, en el inspector veo que la opcion efectivamente lleva la clase dropdown-item  .dropdown-item:focus
{
  color: #16181b;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #adb3ba;
}

Comment: Bien entonces vas por el camino adeuado al menos, tendras que probar con especificidad, o asegurarte que tus estilos sean aplicados despues de los de Bootstrap

Comment: Debes añadir el código HTML para que podamos ver el problema  en la propia pregunta y de ese modo sea más fácil ayudarte. Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.